# Why does remapping key interfere with FormatTime?

Tags: autohotkey, levels

I have this code:

```
FormatTime, CurrentYearMonth,, yyyy-MM
MsgBox, %CurrentYearMonth%
f3::Run D:\folders\%CurrentYearMonth%

a::a
```

Pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> only opens D:\folders, and there is no message pops up. In order to make it work properly, I need to use

```
#InputLevel 1
FormatTime, CurrentYearMonth,, yyyy-MM
MsgBox, %CurrentYearMonth%
f3::Run D:\folders\%CurrentYearMonth%

#InputLevel 0
a::a
```

But I don't understand why this should be the case. I read about [#InputLevel](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm) and [SendLevel](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendLevel.htm#Parameters) but I don't understand much. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your code is after the top [auto-execute section of your script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto), this will mean your <kbd>F3</kbd> hotkey (`f3::`) will execute only that line and `%CurrentYearMonth%` will not be populated. You could format your code like this,

```
f3::
FormatTime, CurrentYearMonth,, yyyy-MM
MsgBox, %CurrentYearMonth%
Run D:\folders\%CurrentYearMonth%
return
```

<kbd>F3</kbd> will run all the code from `f3::` until `return`. This is easier to read and understand.
More details on return - https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Return.htm

Comment: this is a solution, but do you know why the initial code doesn't work?